# Decode private relay email

Tags: android, ios, react-native, base64

I'm developing Apple Authentication feature on Android with React Native, using this library: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication. Everything goes fine, but there is still a thing I want to show in the form is that the real email, or Apple ID of the user. The default settings of Apple accounts is that use private relay, so after I call signIn() method in this code fragment

```
// App.js

import { appleAuthAndroid } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

async function onAppleButtonPress() {
  // Generate secure, random values for state and nonce
  const rawNonce = uuid();
  const state = uuid();

  // Configure the request
  appleAuthAndroid.configure({
    // The Service ID you registered with Apple
    clientId: 'com.example.client-android',

    // Return URL added to your Apple dev console. We intercept this redirect, but it must still match
    // the URL you provided to Apple. It can be an empty route on your backend as it's never called.
    redirectUri: 'https://example.com/auth/callback',

    // The type of response requested - code, id_token, or both.
    responseType: appleAuthAndroid.ResponseType.ALL,

    // The amount of user information requested from Apple.
    scope: appleAuthAndroid.Scope.ALL,

    // Random nonce value that will be SHA256 hashed before sending to Apple.
    nonce: rawNonce,

    // Unique state value used to prevent CSRF attacks. A UUID will be generated if nothing is provided.
    state,
  });

  // Open the browser window for user sign in
  const response = await appleAuthAndroid.signIn();

  // Send the authorization code to your backend for verification
}
```

I got an id_token, after I decode the token, I got an object in this pattern:

```
{
"aud":"",
"auth_time":,
"c_hash":"xxxxxxx",
"email":"xxxxxxx@privaterelay.appleid.com",
"email_verified":"true",
"exp":1663743691,
"iat":1663657291,
"is_private_email":"true",
"iss":"https://appleid.apple.com",
"nonce":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"nonce_supported":true,
"sub":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

whose the email is not the real email that the user entered before. So this can cause a confusion after that when I show the user's information in a form to confirmation, I can only use this private relay email. I wonder that whether any way to decode this email to get the real one, by using c_hash for instance.

Comment: If you could "decode" the email there would be no point in having the feature in the first place, its entire goal is hiding the original email.

Comment: If the user wants to share their real email with you, they will. If they don't you will get a private relay address. That is the whole point of Sign In with Apple. It puts control in the users hands.

Comment: When you say "the email is not the real email that the user entered before" do you mean that you are already asking the user for their email in your app?  Don't do that. You will probably be rejected by Apple. Simply use the email that you get from Sign In with Apple

Comment: Yeah I know, but I think in many cases, people just confuse because the email showed in the form is totally different from what they entered. I mean many people even don't know about private relay, because it is set by default.

Comment: So? Nobody is forcing you to show the user the email.

Comment: Well, actually the tester, but I explained and well, she accepted. Thanks a lot.